# SELECT aggregate values with distinct as columns

Tags: sql-server

Looking for assistance in writing a SQL Query to return data in a particular format. My table has the following structure

Table name: `ExpiryTable`

```
FRUIT   |  EXPIRY
--------+--------------
Apple   |  Monday
Apple   |  Wednesday
Banana  |  Tuesday
Orange  |  Monday
Orange  |  Tuesday
Pear    |  Monday
Pear    |  Tuesday
Pear    |  Wednesday
```

The output I need would show the following, where the fruits go across the result set as columns. This means that this week there are 4 fruits, next week there could be 7 fruits, so it has to factor in that the columns may expand or collapse.

```
          |  Apple |  Banana |  Orange |  Pear
----------+--------+---------+---------+-------
Monday    |  1     |  0      |  1      |  1
Tuesday   |  0     |  1      |  1      |  1
Wednesday |  1     |  0      |  0      |  1
```

With regards to the rows, the days will actually never change. There will only ever be a Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday in the expiry cycle.

I do have another table which contains the complete list of available fruits sold, if that helps with the SQL statement in any way.

Table name: FruitMaster

```
Fruit
-------
Apple
Orange
Pear
Watermelon
Banana
Orange
Rockmelon
Tangerine
Kiwi-fruit
```

All I have thought of to tackle this is selecting the distinct expiry from `ExpiryTable` and then `LEFT JOIN` the aggregate of each fruit, however I am not sure how I would factor in where this week there is 4 fruits expiring, and next week there is more or less. If it was always a fixed list of Fruits I could get way with this technique, but alas its not.

Any assistance would really help me in getting started on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use pivoting logic here:

```
SELECT
    EXPIRY,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN FRUIT = 'Apple'  THEN 1 END) AS Apple,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN FRUIT = 'Banana' THEN 1 END) AS Banana,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN FRUIT = 'Orange' THEN 1 END) AS Orange,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN FRUIT = 'Pear'   THEN 1 END) AS Pear
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    EXPIRY;
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the suggested answer, but not sure how this will address where a new fruit is added to the Table from week to week. For example. This week there are those 4 fruits, but next week there might be 5 fruit boxes expiring. E.g 'Pineapple'

Comment: You would need to add a new count statement for that new fruit.  If you want a query which is completely dynamic with regard to automatically covering any fruit, then you would need to use dynamic SQL for that.

Comment: Would it help if I had another table which listed the available fruits we sell? For example it could contain 50 fruits, but then the SQL statement would just need to factor in any fruits and aggregates for expiry, that exist within that master table?

Comment: That wouldn't change my comment above.  Either you add counts for each fruit manually, or you have to write code which generates something looking like the above.

Comment: Thanks Tim, appreciate the response. I'll take your code now and try and work it into my application and come back. I understand what you mean about the counts, and if this is the way to achieve it, then i think it might be O.K also. Just means I will have about 50 counts in the statement.